# How to change background color of a section on my website?

Tags: html, wordpress, png

How can I change the background the of the container (grey part) from my WordPress website? I want to make it transparent or solid color.

[image: Screenshot of website]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about the [best way to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your post to meet the guidelines. This will make it a lot easier for the community to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you mean by grey part.
Generally speaking, a website is composed of HTML elements `<html>` like this. When you want to change the look of an element you use the CSS file linked to it `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>` (in most cases)
if you know what is the container you can edit the css file with something like this:

```
container-you-are-speaking-of{
    background-color: white;
}
```

if this was not helpful I will need some extra information or at least a bit of code to work with.
Have a good day

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I am not sure if that will work because what I did was to convert pdf to html then add it to my website so that no one will be able to download it and now I cant change the background color

Comment: When on your website, you press f12, you can click a button on the top left corner that allows you to inspect your website. If you hover on the thing you want to change, does it spot that particular area ?

Comment: No it doesnt spot the area

Comment: Then I don't know how to help you, sorry.